# Multiple functions in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, bing-api

I have this one big multi-functional function:

```
 function trans() {
        var credentials = {
            clientId: 'TurboFanTrans',
            /* Client ID from the registered app */
            clientSecret: 'Gkqa2Ru37DeHAfR4AdH/sj94J5Ge1S8Ad7Spp89MMIs=' /* Client Secret from the registered app */
        };

        translator.detect(credentials, text, detectCb);

        function detectCb(err, from) {
            if (err) {
                sendMain('error', err);
                return;
            }

            translator.translate(credentials, text, from, lang, translateCb);
        }

        function translateCb(err, translated) {
            if (err) {
                sendMain('error', err);
                return;
            }

            console.log(text + lang + "=>" + translated);
        }

    }
```

Assume everything is declared, since its multifunctional, I am doing something wrong when I am calling `trans()` here is the code snippet:

```
case 'translate':
                        text += args[1];
                        lang += args[2];
                        trans();
                        text = "";
                        lang = "";
                        break;
```

When called, since its all messed up, `text` and `lang` return as empty strings(they are originally). Can anyone of you guys help me sort this out whether in code or in my brain? the end result should be the translated text of `text` in the language of anything in `lang`. Thank in advance!

Comment: There are about 573 things that _could_ be wrong in your code or in the service that you're using, but without seeing the full code it's hard to tell. Can you add the full code to a gist on Github or on jsfiddle? The first thing I would see as problematic is that the values of the `text` and `lang` variables are being defined outside of the `trans` method and just assumed to exist inside. But again, 572 other things that could be happening.

Comment: That suggestion you said probably is the problem, but here is the full code: http://pastebin.com/bTH99Q46

Comment: Sooo, that's a lot of code. ;) But looking at it again, I think the specific issue at hand is that you are using an asynchronous service (Bing?) inside the `trans()` function, which means `trans()` will return **before** the translation is complete, at which point you set `text` and `lang` to be blank strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that `trans()` returns immediately because it does not block -- it performs an asynchronous request. So `text = "";` and `lang = "";` are executed before your callbacks in `trans()`.

An easy solution to this is to not use the "global" values and pass in the values instead:

```
case 'translate':
  text += args[1];
  lang += args[2];
  trans(text, lang);
  text = "";
  lang = "";
break;
```

Then change:

```
function trans() {
```

to:

```
function trans(text, lang) {
```

These local variables will then shadow the "globals."